# Google Analytics session tracking on client

Tags: angular, google-analytics

On my website, written on Angular 7, I'm using Google Analytics and want to start using Enhanced Ecommerce to send items impressions and collect some info about them. The problem is that I want to resend impressions after a new GA session has started (for example after 30 minutes of user inactivity), but I can't find some sort of event of GA session expiration.

The only solution I came up with was to write my own analogue of GA session, which would expire on the same cases, but it would cause synchronization problems, as I can't be sure that they would expire simultaneously.

If someone had experience with this case, please, give me some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Session expiration is not managed with an event. Google Analytics knows that the new interaction is sent after 30 minutes from the last interaction sent and initializes a new session. 
you can try to do what you want by simulating its operation based on the rules with which new sessions are started: change of source / medium / campaign or after 30 minutes of 'inactivity' or after midnight.